# golang r.Cookies() not returning any cookies even though there are request cookies

Tags: go, http, cookies, session-cookies, svelte

I have been trying to fix this issue for around a week now and i am clueless. Essentially i am making a website with the help of a friend, they are handling the frontend and i am handling the backend. I have been making an authentication which seems to work. We wanted to implement session cookies, so i tried to implment that by adding a session id in the database with the user id and change it if a user logs in again. We send the session id with a cookie with the username of the user as the title, the code doesn't seem to be returning the cookies though, or detect any, even though there are request cookies (check picture attached below). Here is my code to check whether a cookie exists or not

```golang
func CheckCookies(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, inputtedUser Manager) error {
    db, err := connector.ConnectDB()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer connector.CloseDB(db)

    var sessionID string

    // Logs number of cookies
    log.Println("Number of cookies: ", len(req.Cookies()))
    log.Println("Manager username: ", inputtedUser.Username)

    for _, cookie := range req.Cookies() {
        if cookie.Name == inputtedUser.Username {
            sessionID = cookie.Value
            log.Println("Cookie session id: ", cookie.Value)
        }
    }

    // Check if there is a session cookie, if so login the user
    // If the cookie is set, verify the session
    // session := store.Get()
    var user string

    err = db.QueryRow(`SELECT "username" FROM "teammanager" WHERE sessionid=$1`, sessionID).Scan(&user)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error checking session: ", err)
    }
    if user != "" {
        log.Printf("User %s logged in with session id %s. Redirect to dashboard", user, sessionID)
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("couldn't find a user with the session id specified. Redirect to login")
}
```

And the svelte code for sending the cookie

```html
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { RequestHandler } from './$types';
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { fetchFromBackend } from '../../../util/backendService';

export const POST = (async ({ request }) => {
    const cookie1 = request.headers.get('cookie');

    if(!cookie1) {
        console.error("NO COOKIE");
    }
    const response = await fetchFromBackend('login', await request.json());

    const cookie = response.headers.get('set-cookie');

    if(!cookie) {
        throw error(500, "The backend did not return a cookie.");
    }

    return new Response(null, {
        headers: [
            ['set-cookie', cookie]
        ]
    });
}) satisfies RequestHandler;
```

The cookie is being sent from the front end as there is no console error.

[image: Here the request should contain the session id the user logged with before, and if the cookie exists it logs in, if it doesn't it returns anot]

Here the request should contain the session id the user logged with before, and if the cookie exists it logs in, if it doesn't it returns another cookie with a new session id as a response.What am i doing wrong? do i just not understand how cookies work? Cookies are being saved in the browser btw, i looked at storage and the last cookie is there.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Svelte but, the JavaScript code appears to try to get a cookie from the (outgoing) request (!) headers whereas it should set a cookie in the request headers. The Go code looks for cookies in the request (correctly) but you do not show any code where the cookie is being written to the `ResponseWriter`. You can use `http.SetCookie`.

Comment: You can try `curl` to set a cookie to test your Go code too: `curl --verbose --post --cookie "{key}={val}" {endpoint}`

Comment: Couple of other points. While you're entirely able to rename your handler's `http.ResponseWrtiter` to `res` and `*http.Request` to `req`, conventionally these are `w` and `r`. Changing them makes reviewing code slightly more difficult. Also, you can get a cookie from the `*http.Request` by name e.g. `r.Cookie(inputtedUser)`

Comment: [A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie API; it's only sent to the server.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies). you won't be able to see the cookie from javascript, nor do you need to.

Comment: Can you show the output of the Go program to go along with the request in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the solved the specific issue i had, but i changed my approach to using gorilla/sessions instead of reading the cookies myself. Here is my code for it if it helps

```golang
func HasSessionAlready(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, inputtedUser Manager) error {
    db, err := connector.ConnectDB() // connecting to database, this is a function i made
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer connector.CloseDB(db)

    var sessionID string

    // Check if there is a session cookie, if so login the user
    // If the cookie is set, verify the session
    // session := store.Get()
    var user string

    session, err := store.Get(req, "session")

    if err != nil || session.Values["authenticated"] == nil {
        log.Println("Unable to get session: ", err)
        return errors.New("couldn't find a user with the session id specified. Redirect to login")
    }

    sessionID = session.Values["sessionId"].(string)
    log.Println("Session ID: ", sessionID)

    err = db.QueryRow(`SELECT "username" FROM "teammanager" WHERE sessionid=$1`, sessionID).Scan(&user)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error checking session: ", err)
    }
    if user != "" {
        log.Printf("User %s logged in with session ID %s. Redirect to dashboard", user, sessionID)
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("couldn't find a user with the session id specified. Redirect to login")
}
```